# Can I upgrade to 19.04 without losing all my settings and customisations

Tags: upgrade

Like most Linux users, I have heavily customized my version of Kubuntu. Is there any way to keep all these customization's after upgrading to 19.04. I've also done a lot of work to configure the system to my exact needs (Unfortunately I've not taken notes on what I've done through the years.) I've set up a web/file server that I use every day and don't want it to be affected by upgrading the system. All my important files are on separate external hard drives so it's not so much my data that I am worried about, but more the customization's. Is there any way to upgrade but keep all the settings and customization's?

Edit: Upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04

Comment: When installing ubuntu I usually make a separate '/' root partition and '/home' partition so that when I upgrade all of the files in /home are kept as well as my settings.

Comment: From which version do you want to upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't do this. I remember getting the option when I was installing 18.04 but I never thought about it affecting me at the time and as the boot drive of my server is only a 250GB SSD I didn't want break up the drive into separate partitions in case I ran out of space. Now I really wish I had. If there is no way to do it, I may just have to bite the bullet and format the drive and start again.

Comment: It is actually not possible to upgrade directly (easily) from 18.04 to 19.04. You first have to upgrade to 18.10 and from there to 19.04. Also, you may want to look into [timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) for more peace of mind before attempting the update.

Comment: 18.04 is a LTS so it is supported for 5(maybe 10) years.  19.04 is only supported till Jan. 2020.  Unless 19.04 has something you need, it might not be worth it.  Can also try to play around with virtualbox to see if 19.04 is something you want, and not mess up your system.

Comment: I have been using 19.04 through a liveUSB for the past couple of days and it seems significantly faster and smother than 18.04. (Although it is using the Unity DE and not the Plasma DE, which my computer currently uses.) I realize that I'll have to wait until 20.04 for the next LTS release, but I thought with the performance upgrade I've seen it would be beneficial. Maybe I'm just seeing it as smother because it is more lightweight running off of a LiveUSB?

Comment: You can move home directory from "/" to it's own "/home" partition using rsync, (or grsync), and then update /etc/fstab. To complete upgrade reinstall any missing programs.

Comment: Should try a live usb that is as close as possible to what you have now, and see if the performance is still there.  Play around a bit with live usb or virtualbox and see what you like.  19.04 is still on the new side so it might have a few bugs yet.  If you can set up a VM with 18.04 then you can update that to 18.10 to 19.04 and see what happens.